# How angular renders templates when there is a recursive call?

Tags: angular

I am trying to implement a simple directory menu where directories can have children and be part of a parent directory.

However, a very strange thing happens when I implement a recursive template, whenever I click one of the `<li>` elements the function `doSomething` is called, why is this happening? does that mean angular renders the elements over and over again every time I click any `<li>` element? Isn't this a memory leak?

Template:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let d of dirs" (click)="clicked()">
    {{d.name}}
    <ul>
      <hello
        *ngIf="d.dirs && d.dirs.length>0"
        [dirs]="d.dirs"
        [some]="doSomething()"
      ></hello>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Component:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  templateUrl: "hello.component.html",
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`]
})
export class HelloComponent  {
   times: number = 0 ;

  @Input() dirs: Directory[];
  @Input() some;
  constructor() {
    this.dirs = [
      new Directory(
        [new Directory([new Directory([], "sub-sub-dir1")], "sub-dir1")],
        "dir1"
      ),
      new Directory([new Directory([], "sub-dir2")], "dir2"),
      new Directory([], "dir3")
    ];
  }

  doSomething() {
    console.log("Something's been done ! ");
    console.log(this.times++);
  }


  clicked(){ 
    window.alert("Ops I was clicked!")
  }
}

export class Directory {
  dirs: Directory[];
  name: string;

  constructor(dirs: Directory[], name: string) {
    this.dirs = dirs;
    this.name = name;
  }
}
```

Full code is here
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-yvu84v?file=src/app/hello.component.ts

https://angular-ivy-yvu84v.stackblitz.io

Comment: I think you need to stop propagtion from events in this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not related to propagation, it's happening because you're binding a function expression instead of declaration, change it to this and it will work:

```js
 <hello
        *ngIf="d.dirs && d.dirs.length>0"
        [dirs]="d.dirs"
        [some]="doSomething"> 
 </hello>
```

---

### Explanation of why this is happening:

This is happening because of how angular Change Detection mechanism works, Angular executes expressions on each change detection run, which is why your function got executed many times.

Because of that my rule of thumb is to try to avoid using function expressions in `templates`, because they will get executed a lot and it can affect performance.

---

### Brief explanation about change detection:

To help understand why this is the case better, let's explain Change Detection. Your entire component HTML is being represented as a `View`, the view is a data structure that contains all your elements and their property bindings.

If you have `<input [value]="certainVariable"/>`, the input element is being represented with the element and the corresponding binding, so in our case `input: certainVariable`.

Every time a component fires an event, or an Observable emits an event, a Change Detection happens. This is why when you click on an element you're invoking Change Detection, because you are firing an event which triggers change detection automatically.

What Angular does, is that it goes through your entire `View` and checks each element with its corresponding binding to see if a value has updated. If so, it updates it in the DOM as well.

This is how Angular keeps your component logic and your HTML view in sync.

Specifically what Angular does is that it checks each element and its expression, so for example our input element, it checks the `certainVariable` value and see if it has changed.

When you have a function as property binding like this `[some]="doSomething()"`, it will do the same thing as in Change Detection Angular checks an expression.

If you have a function declaration instead, it will not call that function because it's not an expression.

Comment: so clicking an <li> element is considered a change detection?

Comment: also what would be the difference between [some]="doSomething" and [some]="doSomething()"

Comment: In order to answer that question I have to explain more about the Change Detection mechanism, I edited my answer with more info.

Comment: Ok, thanks I will read about it. I knew it has to do something with data binding but I am not a front-end developer, thanks for the answer :)

Answer (score -1):

You are calling your component recursively:

```
selector: 'hello',
```

and in the HTML template/view of the 'hello' component you are calling it again inside itself:

```
...
  <ul>
     <hello ...
```

This means, with every click you get a whole new instance of the component 'hello' inside the parent component: 'hello'.

So, it is behaving the way you see and it is a correct behavior. You must rethink your design if you need a different behavior.

Comment: Can you explain a little more? How come clicking a <li> component create a new instance inside the parent component?

Comment: With each recursive call, you are creating a new entire component and entire set of your dirs, so naturally, each click will trigger whatever is inside.  You can verify that your children fn. calls will re-occur more times the deeper the tree. You need to make the recursive calls for the individual nodes, not the whole tree  structure.